# minimize and maximize multiple bootstrap modal using Angular 4 or 5

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I am looking for minimize and maximize multiple modal using angular 4 or 5 , there are good examples or plugins available in jQuery but not in angular .
I am looking for exactly same functionalities like below GitHub article which is in JQuery :

https://github.com/ROMB/jquery-dialogextend

Thanks in Advance , Please help in this regard.

Comment: Angular and jQuery are not frameworks that were designed to solve the same kind of problem.  jQuery aims to assist with DOM manipulation, while Angular aims to help with Data Binding, and encourages not manipulating the DOM.  You **can** manipulate the DOM using raw Javascript or jQuery code or any other library within an Angular app if you wish, though, but you shouldn't expect Angular to solve the problem for you.  Also, requests for pre-written 3rd party libraries are considered off topic here anyway.

Comment: You might want to do some research on Angular friendly UI frameworks like Angular Material or UI-Bootstrap, maybe one of those frameworks has what you need.